# Create a dictionary key by default in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary

I have a part of code in C++, where I have to increment value of a specific key and if that key doesn't exist the value is zero initialized.

```
++errorboard[dt[dt.size() - 1][value.first]][value.second];
```

So I want to know if in C# exist any method like this?

Comment: `dict[key] = dict.TryGetValue(key, out int value) ? value + 1 : 0` ?

Comment: The `ConcurrentDictionary` does have a `GetOrAdd` method, but the standard dictionary does not have an equivalent. The TryGetValue is your best option.

Comment: From what you are saying I understand that `errorboard` is a dictionary. But it is not clear what is the type of its values. Could you specify?